# Cell is not show after the height have changed from 0 to default size

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to implement a static table view that, depending on the option the user have selected, hide or show the different table view cell.

[image]

When "Repeat" is "Never" a cell should not be shown, but when "Repeat" is anything else, it should show "Repeat End" cell.

[image]

Now the problem is that when I select the repeat value from "Never" to anything else { meaning that I have changed the status of the cell from hidden to un-hidden } the cell is show in blank.
[image]

I have implemented the show and hidden by using heightForRowAt

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let defaultHeight = super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
    let heightIndexPath: [Int: [Int: CGFloat]] = [1:
        [sectionRow.startDateTimePicker.rawValue : startDateEditing ? startDateTimePickerCell.contentView.subviews.first?.frame.height ?? 0 : 0,
         sectionRow.startDateTimeZone.rawValue : startDateEditing ? defaultHeight : 0,
         sectionRow.endDateTimePicker.rawValue : endDateEditing ? endDateTimePickerCell.contentView.subviews.first?.frame.height ?? 0 : 0,
         sectionRow.endDateTimeZone.rawValue : endDateEditing ? defaultHeight : 0,
         sectionRow.repeatEnd.rawValue : repeatValue == Event.Repeat.Never ? 0 : defaultHeight]]
    let cellHeight = heightIndexPath[indexPath.section]?[indexPath.row] ?? defaultHeight
    let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    cell.isHidden = cellHeight == 0 ? true : false
    cell.alpha = cellHeight == 0 ? 0 : 1
    return cellHeight
}
```

I have even tried to change the isHidden and alpha value of the cell, but it still does not show. But strangely, when I change the value (which is not never) the cell appears again.

Is there something that I have missed out to show this hidden cell?

By the way, I am refreshing only the hidden cell when the repeat value is changed as below. I even tried it with reloading the whole table but it did not work.

```
internal var repeatValue = Event.Repeat.Never {
    didSet {
        repeatLabel.text = repeatValue.rawValue
        let indexPaths = [IndexPath(row: sectionRow.repeatEnd.rawValue, section: 1)]
        tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
        // tableView.reloadData() // Tried this also.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead override `tableView(tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:)`

Call the super implementation then subtract 1 when you want to hide the row. Now you will be able to animate the row show/hide by calling 
`deleteRows(at:with:)` or `insertRows(at:with:)` as appropriate.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    var numberOfRows = super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)

    if (section == RepeatSection && shouldHideRepeatEnd()) {
        numberOfRows = numberOfRows - 1
    }
    return numberOfRows
}
```

This will look way nicer

Comment: Do you have a sample source that I can refer to?

Comment: Does this work for static table view? I seem to get runtime errors when insertRows(at: with:) is called.

Comment: sorry. I pressed the wrong button and gave the bounty to somebody else. I appreciate your answer am willing to give you the credit if I can.

Answer (score 1):

I simulated your situation.

`tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)` really lead strange situation.

But

`tableView.reloadData()` works

notes that I use `done` button to toggle value of `Repeat`

[image: Workable Demo]

My code:

```
var event_Repeat_Never = true {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

@IBAction func test() {
    event_Repeat_Never = !event_Repeat_Never
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let defaultHeight = super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
    var cellHeight = defaultHeight
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 4 {
        cellHeight = event_Repeat_Never ? 0 : defaultHeight
    }
    let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    cell.isHidden = cellHeight == 0 ? true : false
    cell.alpha = cellHeight == 0 ? 0 : 1
    print("\(indexPath), \(cellHeight), \(cellHeight == 0 ? true : false), \(cellHeight == 0 ? 0 : 1)")
    return cellHeight
}
```

Comment: Probably the simulation that you are doing differs from mine. As I have mentioned in my question (actually in my code), reloadData does not work also. # Probably something to do with seque and dismiss.

Comment: Also, if i use the reloadData, the animation is not affected.